# Unexpected behaviour of If-Else

Tags: php, if-statement, yii2

I tried to show a login/logout link in my header based on the value in session. i tried some thing like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">

                        <li><a href="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( [ 'site/contactus' ] ); ?>">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( [ 'site/modules' ] ); ?>">FAQ</a></li>
                        <?php
                        $session = Yii::$app->session;
                        $user_id = $session->get('userid');//print_r($user_id);die();
                        if($user_id != null)
                        {?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( [ 'userdetails/logout' ] ); ?>">Logout</a></li>
                        <?php}
                        else 
                        {?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( [ 'userdetails/login' ] ); ?>">Login</a></li>
                        <?php } ?>  

                    </ul>
```

then both links didn't appeare in the header(login/logout). then after a lot of trying i came up with this code

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">

                            <li><a href="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( [ 'site/contactus' ] ); ?>">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( [ 'site/modules' ] ); ?>">FAQ</a></li>
                            <?php
                            $session = Yii::$app->session;
                            $user_id = $session->get('userid');//print_r($user_id);die();
                            if($user_id != null)
                            {
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( [ 'userdetails/logout' ] ); ?>">Logout</a></li>
                            <?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( [ 'userdetails/login' ] ); ?>">Login</a></li>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>              
                        </ul>
```

the code is actually same but i have added some spaces between the curly brackets'{'. And it works as i intended. Is space an issue when we use html and yii2 code combined?

Comment: try to use `!empty($user_id)`

Comment: session had value even then no link appeared. also even if condition failed the else should have worked but it didnt

Comment: `<?php}` is not valid. there HAS to be a space after php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Yii, it is simply a php syntax problem (you should always have a space after `<?php`)...

If you want to mix condition and html output, and have a better readability, you should use this :

```
<?php if ($user_id != null) : ?>
Output 1
<?php else : ?>
Output 2
<?php endif; ?>
```

Read more : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1):

There **HAS** to be a space after the opening `<?php` tag, which means `<?php}` is not valid:

without space:

```
$ cat z.php
<?php if(true) {?>
true
<?php} else {?>   // note, no space after <?php
false
<?php }?>
$ php z.php
true
<?php} else {?>
false
```

with space:

```
$ cat y.php
<?php if(true) {?>
true
<?php } else {?>
false
<?php }?>
$ php y.php
true
```

Note the difference in output. This has nothign to do with Yii, and everything to do with your core PHP coding.